# Camel Simple dynamic expression for dsl

Tags: apache-camel, el

I have a case in camel xml DSL that gets its statement from another statement. And I want it to be like this:

```
${${in.body.eval_code}}
```

I have looked but could not found a sample like that.

Any ideas?

Thx

EDIT: assume in.body.eval_core is another eval like 'in.body.a'. SO when the first one resolves, the final statement will be '${in.body.a}'.

Comment: Not sure I follow, isn't it ${in.body.eval_code} ? You just want to evaluate the body. What else is there to evaluate after that?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti thx for the reply. Edit has been made